# How to stop a calculation if a cell is filled, while retaining the last value calculated

Tags: excel, vba

[This is a sample portion of how I'm keeping the record[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEM3d.png)I want to keep record of the time passed since a certain entry. Initially I had this as:

```
=NOW()-[@[Timestamp column(mmm/dd/yyyy h:mm)2]]
```

However, I want the calculation to stop when a cell is filled (indicating a decision made regarding the entry). I managed to come up with this:

```
=IF(NOT(U5<>""), NOW()-[@[Timestamp column(mmm/dd/yyyy h:mm)2]],"")
```

This leaves me with a blank when the cell is filled. But I want the cell to have a record of how long it took for the decision to be made.

How can I keep the last calculated value?

Comment: Need some more context here... where is the data being printed?

Comment: In that same cell where the equation is. I will attache a picture.

Comment: Are you able to use a helper column?  Essentially, when (arbitrary) Column M has data entered, Column N is filled with the timestamp for "now".  Column O has data entered and Column P is filled with the timestamp for "now".  Column S (per your image) is then the difference in time between P and N.  Is it an issue that "now" is always changing, or do you want finite "now" (e.g., yesterday's now stays or now updates with every day)?

Comment: The take away from the above comment is stating that, with a formula only, you need to base it off of existing data, and you can't go back to old data if it has been updated without having stored the old data elsewhere.

Comment: So this particular sheet pulls data from another workbook, where the initial entry date is registered. I have that date copied and pasted as a value, not as "now", and so in column S, I'm keeping track of the time passed between the original date of entry and now. Then once a decision is made and filled in in column U, I want a record of how long the entry remained in "limbo" before a decision was made.

Comment: Is there a timestamp for column U calculated?  This may need to be where VBA could help where if data is filled into U, then S shows the difference between your other sheet's timestamp; that timestamp for U is your key (for all i know the decision could be what is entered to U, but i don't have that info).

Comment: You just gave me a really great idea, the U column only has the decision status in it. no time stamp. If I add a timestamp column I can make it conditional so that if the cell is empty, it calculates now - entry date, and if status is filled it will calculate the timestamp - entry date!

Comment: Golden; glad that helps resolve your issue!